# Data selected from dropDown write data from column2 to textBox

Tags: vb.net

Thanks in advance for your help.  I've searched the web and this site and I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

Ok I have an access db with a table named docs.  It has two columns.  One named Docs and the other email.  I know how to tell VB that a value of a texBox = The value selected from the dropDown that is mapped to the first column.

What I can't seem to get the code to do is: When the value is selected from the dropDown, it will make the value of textBox2 by selecting it from the next column over.
Basically if you select say Dr. Smith the value from the next column his email, Smith@abc.org would be the value of a textBox.

I hope I fully explained what I'm trying to achieve.  Please let me know if any other information is needed.  Again thank you all for an help you provide.

Aaron

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  *Code* demonstrating how you are doing things helps clarify things and can make answers more applicable...after all there is more than one way to read from a db, right?

Comment: paste your code for what you have tried so far

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882682/vb-net-filling-textbox-on-combobox-selected-index-changed-with-sql-database